# Second level pseudo selection?

Tags: jquery, pseudo-element

I didn't know if there was a post for this already because I don't know exactly how to word the question, so I'll give an example..

```
<ul class=filters>
     <li class=segment-1>
         <a href="#">Web</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

The code is for a list that filters a gallery when you click a list item.

I'm thinking I should be able use the code to select "Web" for example so that I can automatically filter the gallery upon the page loading.

```
$('element*="Web"').click();
```

Is this the best way to do things? And if it is.. what do I put in place of "element" to select Web

Comment: Perhaps you want the `:contains` jQuery selector

Comment: does *="x" not work in jQuery?
not to mention I still need to know what to replace "element" with

Comment: @BrantBarton No, that does not work in jQuery or CSS. jQuery selectors mimic CSS Selectors.

Comment: You're thinking about the [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) for which that is more or less the correct syntax; however, you aren't trying to select based on an attribute (*though you probably should be*), you're trying to select based on the *content* of the element

Comment: sorry, @KevinB I realized this only works for attributes not elements

Comment: @nbrooks I realized this just before you commented haha. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are better ways, which won't have to be updated everytime the text of your markup changes slightly.

Either add a class to the anchor tag, with some meaningful name related to its purpose, then do the following (I used `navLink` as the class name):

```
$('.navLink').click();
```

Or use the existing markup hierarchy:

```
$('ul.filters > li.segment-1 > a').click();
```

P.S. Note that I fixed the quotation marks around your attribute values in your markup:

```
<ul class="filters">
     <li class="segment-1">
         <a href="#" class="navLink" >Web</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: With this being a wordpress plugin, I'll have to use javascript to add in the class. I'm sure I can figure out how though

Comment: Unfortunately It won't be as simple because I'll need to write a general script that will work on each page. So I'll need to create some variables and a for loop and apply the .addClass to the right list item based on the variables.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('ul.filters li a:contains("Web")').trigger('click');
```

Comment: ok @eteich, the first part makes sense now. but the part I'm confused about is, can I use jQuery to basically auto-click the option for me?
It's not that I want the click to do a separate function.. I just want it to click the link.

Comment: You're looking for the trigger() function.  I updated my example above.